# Odds ratio to Probability of Success

Tags: statistics, probability, logistic-regression

We ran a logistic regression model with `Passing the certification exam (0 or 1)` as an outcome.  We found that one of the strongest predictors is the student's program GPA, the highest the program GPA, the highest the odds of passing the certification exam.

`Standardized GPA, p-value < .0001, B estimate = 1.7154, odds ratio = 5.559`

I interpret this as, with every 0.33 unit (one standard deviation) increase in GPA, the odds of succeeding in the certification exam increased by 5.559 times.

However, clients want to understand this in terms of probability.  I calculated probability by:

`(5.559 - 1) x 100 = 455.9 percent`

I'm having trouble explaining this percentage to our client. I thought probability of success is only supposed to range from 0 to 1. So confused!  Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Your math is correct, just need to work on the interpretation.

I suppose the client wants to know "What is the probability of passing the exam if we increase the GPA by 1 unit?"

Using your output, we know that the odds ratio (OR) is `5.559`. As you said, this means that the odds in favor of passing the exam increases by `5.559` times for every unit increase in GPA. So what's the increase in probability?

`odds(Y=1|X_GPA + 1) = 5.559 = p(Y=1|X_GPA + 1) / (1 - p(Y=1|X_GPA + 1))`

Solving for `p(Y=1|X_GPA + 1)`, we get:

`p(Y=1|X_GPA + 1) = odds(Y=1|X_GPA + 1) / (1 + odds(Y=1|X_GPA + 1) ) = 5.559 / 6.559 = 0.847`.

Note that another way to do this is to make use of the formula for [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit):

`logit(p) = B_0 + B_1*X_1 +...+ B_GPA*X_GPA` therefore

`p = 1 / ( 1 + e^-(B_0 + B_1*X_1 +...+ B_GPA*X_GPA) )`

Since we know `B_GPA = 1.7154`, we can calculate that `p = 1 / ( 1 + e^-1.7154 ) = 0.847`

Answer (score 0):

The change in probability(risk ratio i.e. p2/p1) of the target relies on the baseline probability (p1) and as such isn't a single value for a given odds ratio.

It can be calculated using the following formula:

RR = OR / (1 – p + (p x OR))

where p is the baseline value for p.

Eg.

Odds Ratio  0.1     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.5     0.6

RR(p=0.1)   0.11    0.22    0.32    0.43    0.53    0.63

RR(p=0.2)   0.12    0.24    0.35    0.45    0.56    0.65

RR(p=0.3)   0.14    0.26    0.38    0.49    0.59    0.68

This link elaborates on the formula.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-convert-odds-ratios-to-relative-risks/